# Символ, обозначающий последовательность букв слова C#

Tags: c#

не знаю как грамотно объяснить вопрос, но вот такая ситуация:
вводим слово, а в коде проверяется есть ли в этом слове сочетание символов допустим AB, причем в любом месте...каким символом это обозначить в C#? "*" или что-то подобное, не могу вспомнить(
т.е. вот сюда перед "AB" что нужно поставить?

```
 if (textBox2.Text == "AB")
```

Comment: О-о-очень сумбурно. Дайте попробую расшифровать: Вам надо проверить, есть ли в текущем string-е последовательность элементов?

Comment: именно так)

Comment: регулярки спасут)

Comment: Пока можете глянуть [вот это][1] , а я поищу вариант попроще.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922251/check-for-set-of-characters-in-a-string

Comment: мне кажется там был какой-то символ, типа "AB"+...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str.Contains("AB")
```

Comment: т.е. ввести булевскую переменную?

Comment: разобрался, спасибо!